# Xamarin iOS C# Open Links in Safari from UIWebView

Tags: c#, iphone, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm coding an iPhone app with a UIWebView, in Xamarin using C#.

By default embedded links within the web view open a web page in that same web view. I would instead like them to launch the linked page in a new safari browser instance.

This has been answered for objective C in X-Code but as far as I can see not for Xamarin C#

```
webView.LoadHtmlString(html, new NSUrl(Const.ContentDirectory, true));
```

Thanks in advance

Adam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If loading content into a UIWebView and you want to use Safari to open links, doing it the way described above will get you a blank page. You need to check the NavigationType.

```
private bool HandleShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navType)
{
  if (navType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked)
  {
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request.Url);
    return false;
  }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can open a web page in the brower of the device (Safari) with this command.

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("www.google.com"));
```

You don't have to use `UIWebView` at all. If you want to open some web pages in `UIWebView` and some with `Safari` you need to implement the `ShouldStartLoad` delegate. Here you can determine whether to open the web page in `UIWebView` or rather in `Safari`.

```
private bool HandleShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
{
    // you need to implement this method depending on your criteria
    if (this.OpenInExternalBrowser(request))
    {
        // open in Safari
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request.Url);
        // return false so the UIWebView won't load the web page
        return false;
    }

    // this.OpenInExternalBrowser(request) returned false -> let the UIWebView load the request
    return true;
}
```

At last somewhere in `ViewDidLoad` (or other place where you initiliaze the `WebView`) add the following code.

```
webView.ShouldStartLoad = HandleShouldStartLoad;
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest/simplest way to do it is to assign a delegate to the `UIWebView`'s `ShouldStartLoad` property:

```
webView.ShouldStartLoad = (w, urlRequest, navigationType) => {

    // Open the url in Safari here.
    // The urlRequest parameter is of type NSUrlRequest, you can get the URL from it.
    return false; //return true for urls you actually want your web view to load.

};
```

Make sure the delegate returns false, for the links you want to load in Safari, so that your `UIWebView` does not load the link.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, however when I implement that delegate the web view appears blank whereas before I was able to load an html text string in: I'm implementing as follows:

Comment: `code    webView.ShouldStartLoad = (w, urlRequest, navigationType) => {

    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(urlRequest.Url);
    return false;
   };`

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look now. Return true for links you want the web view to load and false for links you don't.