# UIWebView doesn't load pages properly

Tags: uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I'm pretty new to Xamarin and iOS and I am putting together a small POC app to learn.

The app uses a view with a UIWebView in it. I intend to load local web files into it and then manipulate those with a mix of JavaScript and C# (JS bridge) but the UIWebView doesn't function properly. It simply doesn't load the pages. If I uninstall the app and then re-install and run it it often load the web page successfully but in subsequent sessions the web page usually doesn't load, leaving the web view as a white empty area. Just to be sure I have tried to load well known web pages, such as [xamarin.com](http://xamarin.com) or [apple.com](http://apple.com). Again, the first time I run it the pages load but in subsequent sessions they don't. The behavior is the same on a physical device (an iPhone 5) and on the simulator.

Are there considerations as to how the UIWebView needs to be used? The ViewController hosting it is a sub view of a [SlideoutNavigationController](http://dillonbuchanan.com/programming/monotouch-slide-out-navigation/).

I have very little experience with UIWebView so any hints are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:
The code that loads the web view:

```
    WebView.LoadFinished += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Web page was loaded");
    };
    WebView.LoadError += (object sender, UIWebErrorArgs e) => 
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
    };
    WebView.ShouldStartLoad += (UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType) => 
    {
        return true;
    };
    WebView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
    WebView.Layer.BorderWidth = 10;
    WebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("http://www.apple.com")));
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true;
    WebView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
```

Note: The `ShouldStartLoad` event handler is the only one that gets invoked.

This is what the iOS simulator looks like after page (failed to) load:

[image]

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the `UIWebView` is present when you see the white screen? Try to draw red borders around the `UIWebView` just to be sure. And please show us the code where you load the web pages.

Comment: `webView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;` `webView.Layer.BorderWidth = 10;`

Comment: I added the code and a screenie. As you can see the web view is indeed visible. I also tried adding a custom delegate, to see which methods gets invoked. None of the overridden methods got invoked though. Also, can anyone tell me what the bottom translucent surface is? I've double checked the UI designer and no bottom bar has been set for this VC.

Comment: Did you implement the `ShouldStartLoad` delegate? Check out the following answer (you can simply return true in the handler if you want to open every web page in your `UIWebView`) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851412/xamarin-ios-c-sharp-open-links-in-safari-from-uiwebview/21875709#21875709

Comment: Ok, I tried implementing an event handler for `ShouldStartLoad` which just returns true. The handler gets invoked correctly but the page still doesn't load and none of the other event handlers gets invoked.

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? Sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: Not yet but I'm on to something. I went back trying to isolate the problem by creating a new, vresh, view with no logics at all; just a WebView that loads a web page triggered from ViedDidAppear(). That worked every time so I've ruled out my how the VC is embedded within the UI graph.

I then started to recreate the logics that creates the stuff I need to decorate the HTML once everything else works. Basically, what I do is I download objects from a service in background threads and I've now found that if I omit that it all works. I have no idea, however, why my worker threads is interfering.

Comment: The logics running in those worker threads is quite simple: Download a descriptor object, assign parts of the info in that object to the VC view model (VM) object and notify the main thread the info is available. It turns out that just assigning the descriptor object to a property of the VM, from a background thread, is causing WebView to fail, somehow. Currently I cannot dream up the causality. There is no interfering with the foreground thread so I'm clueless right now.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. It turned out loading WebView with (extremely light) HTML content, such as a HTML string, actually required more time than fetching my own objects from a web service. When the data returned by the web service became available WebView still hadn't completed its loading of the web page. So, as my client code got the web service result there was no web page to decorate and the code got in the way of WebViews normal load operation.

This code fixed the sync problem:

```
    private ManualResetEvent _syncLoadWebPage = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private void loadEmptyWebPage()
    {
        const string EmptyHtml =
            "<html><head></head><body style=\"background: aquamarine\"><H1>EMPTY PAGE</H1></body></html>"; 

        WebView.LoadFinished += (sender, e) => webPageReady();
        WebView.LoadStarted += (sender, e) => UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true;
        WebView.LoadHtmlString(EmptyHtml, new NSUrl(AppDelegate.Current.Data.Web.LocalWebRoot, true));
        WebView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
    }

    private void webPageReady()
    {
        _syncLoadWebPage.Set();
    }

    void whenWebPageIsReady(Action callback)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
            {
                _syncLoadWebPage.WaitOne();
                callback();
            });
    }

    void bindMapFile()
    {
        whenWebPageIsReady(() => 
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;
                var snap = new Snap(new WebViewImpl(WebView));
                snap.Image(Model.MapFilePath, "map", 0, 0, Model.MapSize.Width, Model.MapSize.Height);
                // todo Decorate stuff with map here ...
            });
    }
```

All I had to do was to wait for the web page to finish loading and everything seems to work. I simply drew the wrong conclusions from what I saw.

Silly, really.