# How to handle window.open on Xamarin.Forms HybridWebViewRenderer on IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a iOS "app" which is a Xamarin.Forms application which has a HybridWebView for the main functionality and the corresponding HybridWebViewRenderer in the iOS project. Part of the functionality is for some links to open in a new window, and this is done using window.open.

However when these links are clicked nothing happens. How does the UIWebView handle javascript calls to window.open?

The simplest acceptable solution is to make these links open in the Safari (or default) browser.

So how can I force window.open to open in the default native browser?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem? Thanks

Comment: Sorry was too long ago. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851412/xamarin-ios-c-sharp-open-links-in-safari-from-uiwebview